# How to Make a Reversible animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Want to Make a Sliding animation when a button is pressed
And I Want to Ask That How can i bind the button to reverse animation in second click

First Click - Animation
Second Click - Reverse Animation

I Have Tried

```js
function menu_open() {
  document.querySelector('.drop_content').style.cssText = "display: block;";
  document.querySelector('#menu_init').style.cssText = "display: none";
  document.querySelector('#menu_final').style.cssText = "display: block";
}

function menu_close() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("drop_content").style.cssText = ".drop_content {animation: drop_menu_slide 1s reverse;}";
  document.getElementById("menu_init").cssText = "display: block;";
  document.getElementById("menu_final").cssText = "display: none;";
}
```

```css
#dropbutton {
  font-size: 24px;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 12px 9px 12px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.drop_content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -5px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(195, 195, 195);
  padding: 18px;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.dropbutton:focus {
  animation: drop_menu_slide 1s reverse;
}

.drop_content {
  animation: drop_menu_slide 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes drop_menu_slide {
  from {
    margin-left: -30%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

.dropbutton .drop_content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="float: left;">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 18px;" onclick="menu_open()" id="menu_init">
    <hr class="menu_line" id="menu1">
    <hr class="menu_line" id="menu2">
    <hr class="menu_line" id="menu3">
  </div>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 18px; display: none;" onclick="menu_close()" id="menu_final">
    <hr class="menu_load">
  </div>
  <div class="drop_content">
    <a href="index.html"><img style="float: left; margin: 0 0 0 40px;" src="icon.png" width="60" height="60"></a>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-style: normal; font-size: 25px; color: white; font-weight: bolder;">Code With Me</p>
    <hr class="rounded"><br>
    <a style="padding: 7px 152px 7px 152px" href="login()">Login</a><br><br>
    <a style="padding: 7px 140px 7px 140px" href="signup()">Sign Up</a><br><br>
    <hr class="rounded"><br>
    <a style="padding: 7px 145px 7px 145px" href="logout()">Logout</a><br><br>
    <hr class="rounded"><br>
    <a style="padding: 7px 140px 7px 140px" target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/codwithme">Youtube</a><br><br>
    <a style="padding: 7px 128px 7px 128px" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/bhaveshbansiwal">Instagram</a><br><br>
    <a style="padding: 7px 145px 7px 145px" href="bansiwalbhavesh@gmail.com">E-Mail</a><br><br>
    <hr class="rounded"><br>
    <a style="padding: 7px 123px 7px 123px" href="/Webpages/contact_us.html">Contact Me</a><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="location.href='../index.html'" title="Home" id="home_button">Home</button>
<button onclick="location.href='/Webpages/contact_us.html'" title="Contact Me">Contact</button>
<button onclick="location.href='/Webpages/python.html'" title="Python Tutorials">Python</button>
<button onclick="location.href='/Webpages/html_tutorials.html'" title="HTML Tutorials">HTML</button>
<button onclick="location.href='/Webpages/gui.html'" title="GUI">GUI</button>
<button onclick="location.href='/Webpages/about.html'" title="About Us" style="margin-right: 10px;">About Me</button>
<br><br>
</div>
```

I Want to Bind the Button to Two Animation One When Animation and Other Of Reverse Animation to Same Button

Comment: Please show what you have tried. [edit] with a [mcve]. (Read also: [ask])

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML code is a mess. You should only use the style attribute in weird exceptions, and you should never ever style using `float` and `<br>`.

You animation didn't work because you can't animate elements that have `display: none`, so what I did was to just translate the menu to the side and then having it translate back whenever the menu is given the  class `.open`.

Closing the menu should be done by a button or by clicking outside the drawer (preferably on a transparent backdrop), but I just added a simple click anywhere on the menu.

```js
function menu_toggle() {
  document.getElementById('drawer').classList.toggle("open");
  document.getElementById('hamburger').classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
:root {
  --menu-animation-speed-close: 200ms;
  --menu-animation-speed-open: 300ms;
}

#hamburger {
  width: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity var(--menu-animation-speed-close);
}

#hamburger.open {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity var(--menu-animation-speed-close);
}

#hamburger > hr {
  margin: 0.25rem 0px;
}

#drawer {
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: transform var(--menu-animation-speed-close);
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#drawer.open {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transition: transform var(--menu-animation-speed-open);
}

#drawer > .close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial;
}

nav > p.bottom-separator {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div onclick="menu_toggle()" id="hamburger">
    <hr class="menu_line" id="menu1">
    <hr class="menu_line" id="menu2">
    <hr class="menu_line" id="menu3">
  </div>
  
  <nav onclick="menu_toggle()" id="drawer">
    <div class="close-button">X</div>
    
    <p class="bottom-separator">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="icon.png" width="60" height="60"></a>
      
      Code With Me
    </p>
    <p><a href="login()">Login</a></p>
    <p class="bottom-separator"><a href="signup()">Sign Up</a></p>
    <p class="bottom-separator"><a href="logout()">Logout</a></p>
    <p><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/codwithme">Youtube</a></p>
    <p><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/bhaveshbansiwal">Instagram</a></p>
    <p class="bottom-separator"><a href="bansiwalbhavesh@gmail.com">E-Mail</a></p>
    <p><a href="/Webpages/contact_us.html">Contact Me</a></p>
  </nav>
</div>
```